# Reactjs: How to update component when a new prop comes up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update/re-render the component after a new update comes up. All I am doing is:

I have a list of dealers for a casino game, what I want is to add a new dealer, and once the new dealer is added then display it in the view. It is actually happening, but in order for me to see the new dealer, I have to reload the page.

I am not updating the state, I am working with `this.props`. Look at my code

```
@connectToStores
export default class Dealers extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
  }

  static getStores () {
    return [ GetDealersStore, CreateDealersStore ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return {
      ...GetDealersStore.getState(),
      ...CreateDealersStore.getState(),
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
         {!!this.props.dealerData ?
           this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map((dealer) => {
             return (here I am rendering what I need);
          : <p>Loading . . .</p>
      </div>
  }

  _addDealer = () => {
    CreateDealersActions.createDealer({
      DealerName : this.refs.DealerName.getValue(),
      CardId     : this.refs.CardId.getValue(),
      NickName   : this.refs.NickName.getValue(),
    });
  }
}
```

as you see the component above in the code is doing the initial rendering properly, the problem comes up when you hit `_addDealer()`, which is not updating the component, you should reload the page in order to see the new item in the view.

If you do a `console.log(this.props);` within `_addDealer()`, you will get something like this

`{params: Object, query: Object, dealerData: Object, newDealerData: null}`

where `dealerData` holds the full data of the dealers in the view but you can't see there the new dealer created. And `newDealerData` remains `null`

so, what do you think I should do in order to update the component everytime a new prop/dealer comes up ? or how do I update the `props`? which is the proper method in this situation ?

here is the full code for stores and actions just in case

**action**

```
@createActions(flux)
class CreateDealersActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('createDealerSuccess', 'createDealerFail');
  }

  createDealer (data) {
    const that = this;
    that.dispatch();
    axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/create-dealer/create-dealer`, data)
      .then(function success (data) {
        that.actions.createDealerSuccess({data});
      })
  }
};
```

**store**

```
@createStore(flux)
class CreateDealersStore {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      newDealerData : null,
    };
  }

  @bind(CreateDealersActions.createDealerSuccess)
  createDealerSuccess (data) {
    this.setState({
      newDealerData : data.response.config.data,
    });
  }

}
```

**the Dealers component is within a tab named `management`, which is this one:**

```
const menuItems = [
  { route : 'dealers', text : 'Dealers' },
  { route : 'game-info', text : 'Game Info' },
  { route : 'player-info', text : 'Players Info' },
  { route : 'money', text : 'Money' }
];

export default class Management extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    getActivePage : React.PropTypes.func,
    menuItems : React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TabsMainMenu menuItems={menuItems} getActivePage={this._getActivePage} />
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }

  _getActivePage = () => {
    for (const i in menuItems) {
      if (this.context.router.isActive(menuItems[i].route)) return parseInt(i, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which flux framework are you using?

Comment: Can you show the parent component of `Dealers`?

Comment: @E_net4 see the update

Comment: In this case i gonna use _shouldComponentUpdate_ method it takes next props and next states, and you can compare them///

Comment: @The can you give me a little code sample ? I don't see anything in the web. I am just a junior dev, sory.

Comment: You say 'I am not updating the state, I am working with this.props'. If that would be the case, then your component does not need to have any additional code: the parent component will trigger the re-render. However, it looks like your code DOES have a `getPropsFromStores()` function. If these props may change over time, and you need to re-render based on those changes, then you do need to have state in your component. Specifically: put the store info in state, add a listener to changes in store, and do a `setState()` to update your state. Then this will trigger the re-render.

Comment: @wintvelt can you help me with a piece of code please? I am working on my own project and I've been with this for 3 days already. It is my first time working with React, please.

Comment: @wintvelt I am just a Junior dev. I've been reading about the React but still don't get what I need to do here.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I am afraid I am not too familiar with alt or constructors, but it looks like your code is already quite complicated, with react, flux, react-router, and alt library. But at the same time you seem to need help on basic react concepts such as state vs. props. I would advise to start with a entry-level react or alt tutorial (not only read, but also code), and only when you fully understand what your own lines of tutorial code do, then move on. At this stage, I am afraid I cannot help you with lines of code. Sorry.

Comment: @wintvelt should I update the component state from the component or from the Stores ? the only part where I am using the state is in the stores.

Comment: I think in alt stores have state too. Components (which render stuff) come in 2 flavours: *stateless* = components that do not have state, and simply receive props form their parent and render. Stateless components do not get their own data from stores, they simply receive props from parents. *stateful* components do have state: they may get data from the oustide world (a store if you apply flux) and render this data (in which case they also need to listen to store updates, and update state if the store has changed), or they listen to user input and update state.

Comment: @wintvelt I am quitting. I am so frustrated.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) example for you with _shouldComponentUpdate_

Comment: Also in your case you have lots of work with props, instead of using props you should use states. Try to load props and store them in state. And when you change your state _render_ method will be automatically executed. 
P.S [Props vs States](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) it will be useful for you